# Child RelativeLayout to Fit to Parent RelativeLayout of listview item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I try to decorate ListView items which have overlayed orange bar at the leftside of the item as attached image below.

[image]

The layout XML file is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutQuestionItemBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        >

    <!-- SOME VARIABLE HEIGHT CONTENTS -->

</LinearLayout>

<!-- leftside orange bar decoration -->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The XML code above has `LinearLayout` as a decorate child, but it doesn't matter to use `RelativeLayout` or other methods.

StackOverflow articles have activity-based approach but I need to use in `ListView` items with Adapter. what can I do?

**== EDIT ==**

Sadly, I cannot accept both 2 answers below, because two answers are identical to use `LinearLayout` (stacked left to right) as parent. Maybe there is no way to fill child height to parent as overlayed with `RelativeLayout`....

Comment: You're fixing the height of the orange bar to 50dp using `android:layout_height="50dp"`. Why does it surprise you that it doesn't adjust to the height of the variable height layout?

Comment: @Squonk // doesn't matter. it is just one of my trial-and-error bits. The problem is, it is hard to fit the orange bar height to variable height of parent.

Comment: @Squonk // I editted XML code for clarify question.

Comment: Two questions. 1. Have you tried this on an actual device? I find the UI design tools often don't show accurate representations of layouts without having valid data in them. 2. Have you tried a `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` for your linearLayoutQuestionItemBody ?

Comment: @Squonk // answer to 1> Yes. I always did with two actual devices for compatibility (JellyBean and Froyo). answer to 2> I tried with `FrameLayout` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this..

change the main relativelayout as LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
```

and LinearLayout height match_parent

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>
```

Comment: I tried your code but I don't know why the orange bar is not shown. I agree with your approach but android does not give the result. maybe the height is calculated to zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutQuestionItemBody"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I cannot apply this method because the orange bar has to be overlayed, not stacked.